# How test show/index request with dredd + rails?

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary

I wonder how should I test rails api with [dredd](https://github.com/apiaryio/dredd), specially the show and index actions(**/post{id}** and **/post**)

1. Should I fill my database with records before running [dredd](https://github.com/apiaryio/dredd), I mean creating record post with id: 1 and so on?
2. Does dredd always trying to get object with id: 1 ( /post/1 )?

I found example project https://github.com/theodorton/dredd-test-rails but there is only one method(post) described in apib file https://github.com/theodorton/dredd-test-rails/blob/master/apiary.apib

Comment: About #2 I found that I can define value for get request so it could be /post/123, by setting example value(  https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/API%20Blueprint%20Specification.md#ResourceParametersSection )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad 1: Yes, you pretty much want to fill it with some data prior running Dredd (and clean it later). **OR** you can rely on the order of operations using the `--sorted` flag while launching Dredd (so a POST called before GET will create the data).

Ad 2: Your findings are indeed correct. What Dredd uses when calling an URI with parameter in is is the example value as stated in the blueprint. For example it will use `0` in call to `/folders/{id}` as defined here https://github.com/zdne/todoapi/blob/master/apiary.apib#L41

Edit:

All Dredd does at the moment is really taking your endpoints as specified in blueprint and calling them with examples values as stated in the blueprint.